# Using something similar to a CASE WHEN in Phalcon query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, case, phalcon, query-builder

```
$fileQueryBuilder->columns(
            [
                "id" => "d.discovered_file_id",
                "company_name" => "d.company_name"
            ]
        );
```

This is the part of my query builder where I mention the column names to be selected/displayed. Can I handle the 'company_name' field to show it's value if it has one, 
and something like 'Not available' if it's empty, in this part of the query builder itself? Is there a way of doing that, like using a CASE WHEN same as in SQL?

What I tried- 
`CASE WHEN d.company_name IS NOT NULL THEN d.company_name ELSE 'Not available' END => d.company_name`
, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't IF better in this case?

`IF(d.company_name IS NOT NULL, d.company_name, 'Not available') as company_name`

Also PHQL only supports case syntac like this:

`CASE column WHEN value THEN some expression ELSE some expression END`

Comment: ok so do I do something like-
"IF(d.company_name IS NOT NULL, d.company_name, 'Not available') as company_name" => "d.company_name"
I tried that but it didnt' work

Comment: No, in your case you need it just like:

`"company_name" => "IF(d.company_name IS NOT NULL, d.company_name, 'Not available')"`

Comment: aah sry I switched the sides.. thanks for your effort.. works perfectly alright